# How can I make my React app run the tests before building?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm using react with Jest. I'd like to run "npm run build" and have my app running all the tests first and then, if  all the tests pass, build the application. I've found a similar question with the following solution:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts test && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

but when I run "npm run build" the test start running, they pass, but nothing happens after that. Do you know what can I do to make "react-scripts build" run after the tests?

Here is my simple test file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import store from '../../redux/store';
import UserPanel from '../Header/UserPanel/UserPanel';

afterEach(cleanup);


test('should render userPanel component', () => {
    render(<Provider store={store}><UserPanel/></Provider>);
    const userPanelElement = screen.getByTestId('user-panel');
    expect(userPanelElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('should open modal when change theme button is clicked', () => {
    render(<Provider store={store}><UserPanel/></Provider>);
    const changeThemeButton = screen.getByText(/change theme/i);
    fireEvent.click(changeThemeButton);
    const modalTitle = screen.getByText(/change theme/i);
    expect(modalTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: So then `react-scripts test` probably fails since `&&` will only run `build` if `test` exists with 0-code

Comment: But they are not falling because the output is : Tests: 2 passed, 2 total

Comment: it will only work if `react-scripts test` has an exit code of `0`. It probaby hasn't

Comment: By default that will _watch_ the tests, you need e.g. [`--watchAll=false`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--watchall) to tell Jest to run once then exit. Also note you can write a `prebuild` script instead of `&&`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, problem solved. I've added a prebuild as you've suggested and now it's working as expected. Thanks man.